# Django Redirect after Login Error

Tags: python, django, authentication

Im new to Django and I know that to redirect after login I have to set the parameter 'page'. But this only works when the login is successful. 
How can i do the same thing when some error occurs?? 


Ps: Im currently also using django-registration with simple backend

Answer (score 1):

I think it's what you are looking for:

```
# Login
def connection(request):

    # Redirect to dashboard if the user is log
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('YourProject.views.home')

    # Control if a POST request has been sent.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None: #Verify form's content existence
            if user.is_active: #Verify validity
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/index') #It's ok, so go to index
            else:
                return redirect('/an_url/') #call the login view

    return render(request, 'login.html', locals())  #You can remove local() it is for user's data viewing..
```

Comment: You will need `from django.contrib.auth import authenticate`

Comment: Very good answer thanks! But I think the problem is with the django-registration, It automatically calls accounts/login if login fails and it has the default template named 'registration/login.html' (using the simple backend). I wish to redirect to other view or call other template dinamically.

Comment: You can add in your setting : `LOGIN_URL = '/login/'`maybe it will resolve your problem. **EDIT :** Or another urls ^^